# Jquery Kenburner Slider - How do I play a local video file

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to play a local video file using Kenburner slider but instead of playing video it starts to download, here is how I am trying to play it :

```
<iframe class=”video_clip” src=”http://localhost/cgi-bin/movies/12/Barbara_Palvin.mp4”></iframe>
```

The link to demo and code is :

```
http://www.dreamtemplate.com/dreamcodes/documentation/sliders2.html
```

Many thanks !!

Tonya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace tag iframe with embed like :

```
<embed class=”video_clip” src=”http://localhost/cgi-bin/movies/12/Barbara_Palvin.mp4”>
```

Comment: Thanks it plays video now but it also prompts to download it, how do I stop it to prompt for downloading